# ESXi 6.5 vsphere client

Tags: vmware-esxi, vsphere-client

I was looking for the proper vSphere client for a new installation of a standalone ESXi 6.5 host.

I read that native vSphere client is no longer available and that a web client is the replacement.

Does the client come pre installed in the ESXi iso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, the client is shipped with the host:

> You don't need to install VMware Host Client separately, if you are running with ESXi 6.0 Update 2 because Host Client is shipped with ESXi 6.0 U2.

[VMware Host Client 1.0 released with vSphere 6.0 Update 2](http://www.vmwarearena.com/vmware-host-client-1-0-released-with-vsphere-6-0-update-2/)